# Divi Template A Few Questions

Tags: plugins, themes, templates

I'm new and getting stuck into to WordPress and really like the Elegant Theme Divi option, however I have a few questions I was hoping someone could help with.

I do require that the site I build can offer the following functionality

The ability to compare products

Ability to register

Online forms that you can complete with your requirements, drop down, text box and icon selections

Those requirements can then be sent to various vendors ominously via the site

The ability for vendors to respond with a quote

The user to be able to review, then select the quote they like and then contact vendor to complete the transaction

All of this to look and remain consistent within the theme of the site

Will Divi theme be able to facilitate this? Or is there another theme that may be more suitable to this type of thing

Sorry if I sound a bit green but a newbie giving it a go and would appreciate some advice

Thanks

http://www.elegantthemes.com/gallery/divi/

Answer (score 0):

Divi will not be able to support all of the features as you've stated out of the box. With integration of things such as WooCommerce which Divi prefers you use, you'll be able to incorporate features like the quote but probably not on the product comparisons.

That being said, DIVI is a very powerful theme, but keep in mind that many themes will need customization for things like e commerce. You may be able to avoid the comparison with a filter to display multiple products of the same time instead if that's a suitable work around. You could also look into SHOPIFY if that management system offers you more of what you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Divi is a template and i think your question have nothing to do with templates. Many plugins added to Divi can do that job (including Woocommerce). Because you are a newbie, i recommenend you Divi. My opinion is that no other template will facilitate this more than Divi. And its commmunity is massive...
So in a conclusion : dig for plugins, dont question Divi as it is not its job.

Answer (score 0):

Really broad question.

Short answer. No theme/template will handle all this. Nor should you want it to.

Compare products can be done with WooCommerce, a free WP plugin. It works well with Divi. If you want to expand on the compare options Automatic sells an extension: https://woocommerce.com/products/woocommerce-products-compare/

You can let users register on any WordPress install. For more control you can use various form plugins. i.e Gravity Forms. 
https://www.gravityforms.com/

I would also recommend Gravity Forms for the rest of your form needs. Really solid product with great support. It can handle all the form related features you've listed.

To keep with consistency of Divi theme you will need to write/use some CSS.
https://divi.space/tutorials/5-ways-to-add-css-to-divi/

WordPress' beauty lies in the modular ecosystem of themes, plugins and custom code. More often than not you won't find a solution to multi-part project using just theme, take advantage of full functionality of the framework.